# flutter RichText, TextSpan align

Tags: flutter, richtext, textspan

this is my code

```
RichText(
          text: TextSpan(children: [
            TextSpan(
                text: 'flutterABC',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: isDesktop(context) ? 64 : 32,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w800)),
            TextSpan(
                text: 'flutterABC',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: isDesktop(context) ? 64 : 32,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                    color: Colors.indigo))
          ]),
        ),
```

like this. i use RichText and TextSpan.
when i run in chrome, i can't control align
if 'flutterABCflutterABC' is one line > align is center.
but if two line > align is start..

i want to always align center
how can i do?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this please

```
             RichText(
                text: TextSpan(
                    children:[
                  TextSpan(
                      text: 'flutterABC\n',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w800)),
                  TextSpan(
                      text: 'flutterABC',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                          color: Colors.indigo))
                ]),
              ),
```

Comment: i want to one line. just i want to two line when width small..

Answer (score 0):

you can use Column to this effect
but if you went to use RichText
you can use \n for newline